# Compare two column in the same worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare data from column B to column AB within the same worksheet. If there is a match, then I want to delete the match from column AB. 
Once the match is complete, I would like to copy the remaining data into column Z.

What I have researched so far is [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/872639-compare-2-lists-adding-missing-data-1st-list-bottom-2nd-list.html), but I am not comparing with the the same column on different workbooks.

I have attached some screenshots seen below:

[ColumnA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaVe9.png)
[ColumnAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf17B.png)

My current code is here `

```
Sub CompareNRemove()

For i = 1 To last_cell_B
        For j = 1 To last_cell_AB
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AB" & j).Value Then
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("b" & j).Value
        End If
        Next j
    Next i

 Next r

 'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB18:AC999").ClearContents
 'Call MatchNSortW

End Sub


For r = 18 To Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row     ' From row 1 to the last row with data
    On Error Resume Next

    myCountif = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, "E")
    myLookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, "E")

    MyAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Application.Countif(Range("AB18:AB999"), Cells(r, "E"))


    If MyAnswer = 1 Then
    Match = Application.WorksheetFunction.Application.VLookup(myLookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB18:AB999"), 1, 0)
    Cells(r, "B").Value = Match


    'Check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Application.VLookup(Match, Range("AB18:AB999"), 0)
    'Cells(r, "D").Value = Check

    'Check it off the list
    'Check = Application.WorksheetFunction.Application.Match(Cells(r, "B"), Range("AB18:AB999"), 0)


    'Checkup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Application.Match(MyAnswer, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB18:AB999"), 0)



    ElseIf MyAnswer = 0 Then
    Cells(r, "B").Value = ""

    End If



 Next r

'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB18:AC999").ClearContents
'Call MatchNSortW

End Sub`
```

Comment: So use the code in the linked article, but change ithe references to point to different columns in the same sheet.

Comment: Your own effort is condition for finding help here. To qualify you need code which you have tried and a point where you have failed.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried that, but it won't let me change the reference point from sheet to sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take the values in column AB that do not exist in column B and put them into column Z. If you also want to remove the duplicated values from column AB then just clear column AB and transfer the same values there.

```
Sub CompareNRemove()

    dim i as long, arrB as variant, arrAB as variant, z as object

    set z = createobject("scripting.dictionary")

    with worksheets("sheet101")

        arrB = .range(.cells(2, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)).value
        arrAB = .range(.cells(2, "AB"), .cells(.rows.count, "AB").end(xlup)).value

        for i=lbound(arrab, 1) to ubound(arrab, 1)
            if arrab(i, 1) <> vbnullstring then
                if iserror(application.match(arrab(i, 1), arrb, 0)) then
                    z.item(arrab(i, 1)) = vbnullstring
                end if
            end if
        next i

        .cells(2, "Z").resize(z.count, 1) = application.transpose(z.keys)

    end with

end sub
```